# Possibility of travelling having registered passport information inside 72 hours

Tags: passports, bookings

In the UK, apparently you need to register your passport information at least 72 hours before arrival. Unfortunately, I didn't get an e-mail from the airline to remind me so I've only just done it (flying Thursday).

Am I still going to be able to fly home?

Comment: Are you flying from or to the UK? Where is the other end?
Pretty sure you'll be fine though - that sounds like an airline "rule", not an actual one.

Comment: @CMaster From the UK to Spain

Comment: Hah, no such requirement. I'll try and source this to answer. Where did you get the idea that it **was** required? (With a link if possible)?

Comment: @CMaster "Due to security regulations, mandatory passport information must be provided at least 72 hours prior to departure for flights to the Great Britain."

Comment: @jumpingcode where did you get that quote?  Which airline are you flying with?

Comment: @CMaster Norwegian

Comment: @jumpingcode that quote says ***to*** Great Britain, not from it.

Comment: @phoog Also, poorly worded. I imagine it's referring to my return flight (also less than 72 hours away)

Comment: Everything I can find suggests that from the UK gove's point of view, as long as they get the data before teh flight arrives, it's fine. The 72 hours thing seems like something Norwegian have come up with.

Comment: @CMaster Here's to hoping ha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can find no evidence on the internet that any such requirement exists.

The UK government (in common with many others) appears to require Advanced Passenger Information (API) for arrivals (and, as of 2015, departures) by ferry, rail or air. However there appears to be no deadline for when this is provided other than the arrival or departure of the vehicle in question. Most airlines and rail providers say they will take this information either in advance (their preference) or at the point of check in.

The UK's API program previously seems to have gone by the name "e-Borders", although that scheme is now defunct.

The 72 hours requirement is presumably on the part of your airline. I can give no guarantees, but I strongly suspect that if you have failed to provide the data with that much notice, that they will tkae it from you wheneer possible and pass it on to the relevant authorities.

Comment: Seems odd right? I can book a flight today and provide that information

Comment: +1, but note...  Not "appears to require", The requirement is part of a full on statutory instrument.  And not 'presumably on the part of...', it is definitely so per the statutory instrument.

Comment: @gayot_fow If you can point me to the law, or openly published UK government information on the law, then great. The "appears" and "presumably" is because all I found was transport company websites mentioning the requirement

Comment: @CMaster, all the relevant links and authoritative sources are here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60584/do-the-immigration-agencies-of-eu-member-states-keep-records-of-eu-citizens-entr/60588#60588

Comment: @GayotFow you're saying only that API (aka PNR) data are definitely required, as seen in the legislation mentioned in your linked answer, correct?  In particular, I think you are *not* claiming that the legislation mandates a 72-hour deadline for providing the data, since I see nothing in the links to indicate that.  (Some links are broken, by the way.)  CMaster seems to think that you *are* saying that your answer concerns the 72-hour deadline ("presumably" appears in reference to that aspect of the question).

Comment: @phoog yes, the information is definitely required and there is no need  to use hedging language like 'appears to' or 'seems to' or 'presumably'. These weakens the answer's canonical value.  Also including the relevant authority in the body of the answer would be helpful because comments are sometimes swept out by moderators.